# Twitter app not showing any pictures

Tags: nexus-5, images, twitter, 5.0-lollipop

I updated my Nexus 5 to the official Android L factory image yesterday, and Twitter was working fine for a while after that. Now, however, the app won't load any images at all--no tweet images, no profile pictures, nothing. If I tap an image I get an icon like I'm disconnected and it can't load.

I've tried clearing the data and force stopping the app, then uninstalling it entirely, but neither approach worked.

How can I get the app to show pictures again?

Comment: This sounds obvious, but do other internet apps work normally? What kind of internet connection is it?

Comment: All of my other apps work as expected. I tried both over wifi and my cellular connection, same problem both ways.

Comment: Yes, the webpage works as expected through Chrome on my phone.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the Twitter app uses data stored at `/sdcard/Android/data/com.twitter.android`. I deleted that directory and reinstalled the app and everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, turned out my Nand flash storage was full. Deleted one file and restarted twitter, all working.